# How to draw (animate) random process from the start (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I want to draw random process path from the begginning (0,0) which is updated step by step. I used matplotlib animation, but it draws a simple line. How to draw a path?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Process simulation (Wiener process)
n = 1000
sd = np.sqrt(0.1)
w = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n-1):
    w[i+1] = w[i] + np.random.normal(0, sd)


# Set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
ax.set_xlim([0, 1000])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 50])
th = np.linspace(0., n, n / 0.1, endpoint=False)
line, = ax.plot([],[],'b-', animated=True)
line.set_xdata(th)



# Animation function
def update(data):    
    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,

def data_gen():
    t = -1
    while True:
        t +=1
        yield w[t]


# Call the animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate your data in a separate script.
2. Save this data to a continuously updating .csv (I prefer to use pandas)
3. Run the graph in it's own console but set it to update based on the csv data(I would use pandas)

Comment: is there a way to somehow modify existing code? Because this is only the part of a big program and additional scripts, data files and so are quite inconvenient..

Comment: I had done a similar project in the past but I can't find it so I'm just trying to write out the code again now.

Comment: I mean, change the function 'animate' or use another in the existing code instead of making .csv file and two additional scripts.

Comment: if your data is being generated in a while loop, the console will keep reading that while loop and it won't execute the rest of your code until the condition to execute that while loop is no longer satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a library I wrote called [celluloid](https://github.com/jwkvam/celluloid). Under the hood it uses ArtistAnimation instead of FuncAnimation, which practically means it isn't very memory efficient. This code took about a minute to run. In my opinion the code is easier to read but I'm definitely biased.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera

n = 1000
w = np.cumsum(np.sqrt(0.1) * np.random.randn(n))
fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(w[:i], color='blue')
    camera.snap()
anim = camera.animate(interval=10, blit=True)
anim.save('weiner.mp4')
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you! although one minute is quite a lot..
is there a way to stop animation at some point by, for example, pressing an enter button?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of anything easy. It's certainly possible but you'd probably need to use Jupyter or some javascript<->python thing like Bowtie or Dash. There might be a builtin matplotlib solution, but if so I've never used it. You'll probably want to ask a new question for that.